# When is variables thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

So i have a very basic question about thread safety of an object... i don't know how to google this question, as it would have been a lot easier.

so if i got a Type like this

```
public class ContainedThread
{
    private Thread _thread;
    private long _closesignal;

    private bool _isResponding = false;
    private object _isRespondingLock = new object();
    private DateTime _lastResponse = DateTime.Now;
    private object _lastResponseLock = new object();

    public ContainedThread()
    {
        _closesignal = 0;
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Main));
    }

    public void Start() { _thread.Start(); }
    public void Join() { _thread.Join(); }
    public bool IsAlive { get { return _thread.IsAlive; } }
    public void Close() { _closesignal = 1; }

    public void Main()
    {
        while (Interlocked.Read(ref _closesignal) < 1)
        {
            //!Simplyfied for Stackoverflow.com!
            lock (_lastResponseLock)
            _lastResponse = DateTime.Now;
            lock (_isRespondingLock)
            _isResponding = true;
        }
    }

    public DateTime LastResponse { get { lock (_lastResponseLock) return _lastResponse; } }
    public bool IsResponding { get { lock (_isRespondingLock) return _isResponding; } }
}
```

If I create and object of this, and run Start, will I then access the variables `_isResponding` and `_lastResponse` safe enough? From both inside the object, and outside with `LastResponse` and `IsResponding`?

I'm a little confused about threads and memory, as I guess Threads does not own memory directly?

Comment: Seems safe individually. But LastResponse und IsResponding look connected. So if you ask for both via 2 different Properties they might not be in ~sync~.

Comment: so using 1 lock would be better?

Comment: If you still ask for 2 Properties that would still be two individual locks. Would make no difference. You need too ask for them in one go with one lock.

Comment: like this?

public object SocketInfo { get { lock (objLock) return new { IsResponding = _isResponding, LastResponse = _lastResponse }; } }

Comment: Ugly Interface but would work. If LastResponse makes only sense when IsReponding is set i would make LastResponse the Out Parameter of a IsResponding method.